# How can I prevent Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code from rendering output multiple times when executing R programs?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

Output generated by executing a R Jupyter Notebook Cell is rendered multiple times.

I followed the instructions in [this](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/jupyter_r_notebooks.html) article to set up Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code for executing R programs. However, when running basic programs, I noticed that the output generated by executing a cell is rendered multiple times. Specifically, the output is rendered a number of times equal to the number of print statements in the cell. I did not encounter this issue when running the same program by saving it to a file and running it using Rscript via the command prompt.

To illustrate this issue, I have included some screenshots below:
[image: OUTPUT repeated twice]

[image: OUTPUT repeated 4 times]

As a beginner in R, I am not sure if this is an expected behavior. If this is the case, I apologize for my ignorance. However, if this behavior is not expected, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to prevent Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code from rendering output multiple times.

VS Code Extensions that I use for R: 1) [R](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r) 2) [R Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RDebugger.r-debugger)

Comment: Dis you get any clue into why this is happening?